# Pyinstaller exe failed to execute script

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe, pyinstaller

So this is my code, I can run it on my computer. As soon as I move it to another computer via flash drive, and try and open it, it reads failed to execute script.
I used Pyinstaller with the commands for -w -F -i.

I've tried on two other computers aside from my own, it works on mine, but not on others. Please help!

```
from wand.image import Image as wand_image
import re
import os
import Tkinter as Tk
from ttk import *
import tkMessageBox
from datetime import datetime
import threading


total_files= 0
files_finished= 0


root = Tk.Tk()                                                                 #Starts the GUI.
root.resizable(False, False)


canvas= Tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
canvas.config(width=500, height=125)
canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,500,500, fill="blue")
canvas.grid(row=0, rowspan=30, columnspan=100)


current_update= Tk.Label(root, text="... Activity Feed...", font="-weight bold", background ="cyan", width=49, height=2, border=0)
current_update.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=100)


current_update_display= Tk.Label(root, font="-weight bold", background ="black", foreground="white", width=49, height=2 , relief= "sunken", \
    text="0 out of 0 files completed.")
current_update_display.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=100, sticky="N")


Progressbar= Progressbar(length=495, maximum=0)
Progressbar.grid(row=6, rowspan=30, columnspan=100)


def get_total():
    global total_files
    for folder in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if not os.path.isdir(folder) or re.search('zzz-Files Without Dates-zzz', folder):
            continue
        for filename in os.listdir(folder):
            file_type= re.search(r"\.\w+", filename)
            if file_type==None:
                continue
            else:
                file_type= file_type.group()
            new_filename= "%s%s" % (re.sub(".pdf", "", filename), " -converted_page.png")
            if not re.search(".pdf", filename) or re.search(" -converted_page.png", filename) or os.path.exists(r"%s\%s" % (folder, new_filename)):
                continue
            elif re.match(r"%s \d{6}%s" % (folder, file_type), filename) or re.match(r"%s \d{6} \(\d+\)%s" % (folder, file_type), filename):
                try:
                    possible_date_code= re.search(r"\d{6}", filename).group()
                    possible_date= datetime(month=int(possible_date_code[:2]), day=int(possible_date_code[2:4]), year=int(possible_date_code[4:])+2000)
                    if possible_date<datetime.now():
                        continue
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            total_files+=1
    Progressbar.config(maximum=total_files)
    current_update_display.config(text="%s out of %s files finised." % ("0", total_files))


def convert():
    global total_files, files_finished
    for folder in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if not os.path.isdir(folder) or re.search('zzz-Files Without Dates-zzz', folder):
            continue
        for filename in os.listdir(folder):
            file_type= re.search(r"\.\w+", filename)
            if file_type==None:
                continue
            else:
                file_type= file_type.group()
            new_filename= "%s%s" % (re.sub(".pdf", "", filename), " -converted_page.png")
            if not re.search(".pdf", filename) or re.search(" -converted_page.png", filename) or os.path.exists(r"%s\%s" % (folder, new_filename)):
                continue
            elif re.match(r"%s \d{6}%s" % (folder, file_type), filename) or re.match(r"%s \d{6} \(\d+\)%s" % (folder, file_type), filename):
                try:
                    possible_date_code= re.search(r"\d{6}", filename).group()
                    possible_date= datetime(month=int(possible_date_code[:2]), day=int(possible_date_code[2:4]), year=int(possible_date_code[4:])+2000)
                    if possible_date<datetime.now():
                        continue
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            with wand_image(filename=r"%s\%s" % (folder, filename),resolution=300) as source:
                images=source.sequence
                wand_image(images[0]).save(filename=r"%s\%s" % (folder, new_filename))
                files_finished+=1
                current_update_display.config(text="%s out of %s files finised." % (files_finished, total_files))
                Progressbar.step(1)
    root.destroy()


for interval in range(2):
    if interval==0:
        thread_object= threading.Thread(target=get_total)
    else:
        thread_object= threading.Thread(target=convert)
    thread_object.daemon = True
    thread_object.start()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright well I ran pyinstaller without -w so the command prompt would still open.

I ran it and got

```
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
```

So for whatever reason it still requires that even after it was made into a exe. So the new device needs it as well, odd but oh well.

This is now a new issue so I'll move on from here, but now I know.
Thanks to everyone who read and commented!

Comment: Yes, Wand requires that Imagemagick be installed. So that makes some sense to me. Transferring all the Python components does not install the non-Python Imagemagick.

Comment: @fmw42 So even though i have it installed on the computer that makes the exe, It will still need it on every other computer it ever goes on?

Comment: I think that is correct. But I am not an expert on Python nor using PyInstaller. I will defer to others more expert on Python and Wand.

Comment: Dang, that's just heart breaking... Oh well, now I know, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are general things you might or might not have thought about:

- Pyinstaller need to have the same type of system to deploy to as the system you are building on.  If you are building on a 64 bit platform then you can deploy to a 64 bit platform.  A 32 bit platform build will deploy to 32 bit platforms.
- So you have path statements that are to the libraries on your computer but those don't exist then you have to bring them with you in the [spec file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html).

I would suggest doing a one directory install rather than a file install for the first attempt, it's slightly easier.

Comment: I thought since I was always just getting the current path the program was in, and it wasn't specific that I wouldn't need the spec file?
And darn is there a way to get around the 32 and 64 bit issue?

Comment: I just checked the other computer to confirm, it is a 64 bit platform same as mine, I also brought over the .spec file and it didn't work. Sadly it looks like those aren't the issues at hand, but thank you for the answer cause I learned something new! ^-^